# What does it mean that GUIkit is being deprecated?

Tags: gui-construction, java, deprecated

What is the disadvantage of using `GUIKit` now? What does it mean that it is being deprecated? Will it be removed from *Mathematica* in some later versions?

Comment: It is not being maintained in any capacity. It is legacy code that is only going to perform worse and worse, I would avoid using it.

Comment: There is at least one package (EquationTrekker) that is still dependent on GUIKit, so unless WRI decides to give that one a (much needed!) makeover, GUIKit is staying. Nevertheless, `Dynamic[]`/`Manipulate[]` is what's recommended for everyday use now, so use that.

Comment: @J.M. Very few people use EquationTrekker and it's not advertised anymore. It's basically dead. I'm pretty sure no one would be interested in re-writing it right now either.

Comment: I should also note that you won't be able to get much help using GUIkit from tech support in the company or professional services.

Comment: @Searke, that's sad to read; I always thought it was at least pedagogically useful…

Comment: @J.M. GUIKit played its major role during the pre-V.6 times. I.e. before the interactive interface features in FrontEnd and their subsequent streamlining. It was very useful to showcase different algorithms in Mathematica through relevant dashboards, etc. (You might have seen [NIntegrate Explorer](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/GUIKit/tutorial/NIntegrateExplorer.html).) And of course to demonstrate the utilization of Java/JLink.

Comment: @Anton, "GUIKit played its major role during the pre-V.6 times." - hah, that's actually why I was quite familiar with it! :D (I should state at this juncture that I was stuck on 5.2 for a long while before I jumped to version 8.) It was nifty for making mock-ups, and was very useful in conjunction with the LiveGraphics3D applet. (Has it been that long ago already?!)

Answer (score 6):

It is an indication that

1. It is no longer under active development (or, really, any).  Bug reports may be ignored unless they have severe impact (like security issues).
2. You should try to port existing code to a new framework, namely built interfaces.
3. It will not be ported along with the rest of the product to new platforms.
4. It may in the future be dropped from the product.  But that is not imminent.

Comment: p.s. thanks for your recent posts on this site, they are really helpful